# Creating files with Ruby

Tags: html, css, ruby, file, sass

Is there a way to create a blank css document file and name it with any resolutions from the Ruby console without searching through a folder? What would be the code?

Comment: Like `touch path/to/css/file.css`? A blank CSS document is literally an empty file.

Comment: @tadman no, I mean while I’m working with html , instead of going to folder and creating something there – just with 2-3 words of Ruby code create an element such as style.css etc. is it possible?

Comment: Anything's possible if you can figure out *how*, but I'm not sure what you're asking for, nor how Ruby is involved here. It sounds like you need a more sophisticated HTML/CSS editor if this is what you want to do.

Comment: I’m searching for a coding solution)

Comment: *Ruby code create an element such as style.css*  --   What do mean by "element" and what do you mean by "style.css"?  There are at least three "technologies" at play here: ruby, html, css.  Try to be specific about which one you are referring to.

Comment: What is "a blank css document"?

Comment: What do you mean by "a file with a resolution"?

Comment: @sawa it was already discussed. File with [.css] extension

Comment: @sawa The question is: how to create a new .css file with Ruby console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> just using a console create a file and name it how I want with any
>   resolutions

What is a "resolution"?  Maybe we can use the following example as a starting point for discussion:

```
$ irb

2.4.0 :001 > File.open('my.html', 'w') {|f| f.puts '<div style="color: red">Hello</div>'}
 => nil 

2.4.0 :002 > exit

$ cat my.html
<div style="color: red">Hello</div>
```

I think I checked off three of your requirements:

1. Used the ruby console.
2. Created a file.
3. Named it how I wanted.

Comment: By “resolution” I meant (.css , .sass, .js etc.). So without closing Ruby console - our goal is to create such file. I guess we have to use File.new(), but how the code will look like?

Comment: @user9330474, Get rid of the .html extension for the file name in the example?

Comment: no, okay, let’s go through it in another way. I mean is it possible to create a new let it be sass file, called style.sass with Ruby through the console, and how?

Comment: @user9330474,  Change the name of the file in the example to style.sass?

Comment: would it work? I mean don’t we use File.new for new files?

Comment: @user9330474,   *would it work?*  -- Either that, or you computer will explode in a huge fireball.  It's 50-50.

Comment: that’s fine, thx )))